# Installing Refiney - ExecJS is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, execjs

When I was trying to install Refinery following the instructions on http://www.refinerycms.com/download , when it was generating the application the error:

```
ExecJS is not installed. Please re-start the installer after running:
gem install execjs
```

was shown.

When I listed my gems, I had several versions of execjs:

```
execjs (2.6.0, 2.5.2, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 1.4.0)
```

I removed them all, and then I installed it again, however the same error was present

Answer (score 1):

After removing all the execjs versions, then I updated the gems:

```
gem update --system
```

and the installation finished succesfully

I hope it helps

Comment: This fix worked for me after also running `gem install execjs` one more time.